# find duplicates in column and appending to internal table

Tags: sql, abap, opensql, internal-tables

I have `internal table` with 5 fields, let them name `F1`, `F2`, `F3`.. and so on.

This table has about 300 rows. Now, based on `F1`, I want to search all rows for duplicates. Then I want to delete all rows which have no duplicate and reduce all founded duplicates to only one record.

*For example:* If there is a record 3 times, I want to write it only 1 time in a new internal table.

I've tried to do it with `LOOP AT` but I could not figure out a good solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863043/extracting-unique-values-from-an-internal-table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920458/new-abap-syntax-instead-of-collect/57921320#57921320

Comment: sort the table by f1 and loop on it. try that and post your code

Comment: You tagged your question Open SQL but nowhere you are talking about a database table.